# Why is pool.map removing data operations?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, immutability

I have a certain function which operates on a globally defined numpy matrix and alters some of the positions in this matrix. I call this function multiple times and alter multiple spots of the matrix. This works perfectly fine and does what I expect when I do standard sequential calls to a function. I wanted to parallelize this with pool, and when I try to do this, it does not save the alterations that the functions produces, and when I print after it is just the original zero matrix. Why is this happening and what is the fix? Code attached:

```
all_mutations = np.zeros(10,10)
parallelMutate(all_mutation_settings[0])
parallelMutate(all_mutation_settings[1])
parallelMutate(all_mutation_settings[2])
print(all_mutations)
#THE ABOVE WOULD WORK
pool.map(parallelMutate, all_mutation_settings)
print(all_mutations)
#This would just give back the zero matrix
```

Comment: you never assign to `all_mutations`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. all_mutations is a variable defined outside of the functions and shared by all calls of the function. I do assign to all_mutations inside of the function when running with a different setting. I edited the code slightly for clarity in how the program is structured.

Comment: **Multiple processes don't share state**. This is very clearly described in the [multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use shared memory to be the backing store for your `np` array:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array
import numpy as np
import ctypes

def to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape):
    '''Create a numpy array backed by a shared memory Array.'''
    arr = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array)
    return arr.reshape(shape)

def to_shared_array(arr, ctype):
    # We do not have to provide a lock if each process is operatying on indidual cells of the array:
    shared_array = Array(ctype, arr.size, lock=False)
    temp = np.frombuffer(shared_array, dtype=arr.dtype)
    temp[:] = arr.flatten(order='C')
    return shared_array

def init_pool(shared_array, shape):
    """ Initialize global variable for each process in the process pool: """
    global all_mutations
    # create np array backed by shared array:
    all_mutations = to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape)

def parallelMutate(tpl):
    # unpack argument
    x, y, value = tpl
    all_mutations[x, y] = value

# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # 10 by 10 array of doubles:
    all_mutations = np.zeros((10,10))
    shape = all_mutations.shape
    shared_array = to_shared_array(all_mutations, ctypes.c_double)
    # now use the shared array as the base:
    all_mutations = to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape)
    pool = Pool(3, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(shared_array, shape))
    all_mutation_settings = [(1,1,1), (2,2,2), (3,3,3)]
    pool.map(parallelMutate, all_mutation_settings)
    print(all_mutations)
```

Prints:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Did this answer your question satisfactorily?